# Write to Pastie or Pastebin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pastebin, pastie

I have an application I'm writing, in Objective-C (iPhone), and I want to be able to write a string of text to Pastie or Pastebin, and be able to have the link to that page. I have not been able to find any API for either of these, is this possible? How?

Comment: If you mean you want to write over the network to pastebin.ca (as an example), there is an API page here: http://pastebin.ca/tools.php

Answer (score 2):

You will have to construct a HTTP POST request with the fields as described in the `<form>` tag on the html page.

for pastebin.com it would probably be `parent_pid`, `format`, `code2` and `poster`.

Just make sure that the owner of the site doesn't have any problems with your program accessing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is their API for pastebin.com: http://pastebin.com/api